# May a Muslim attend a wedding where a Muslim woman marries a non-Muslim man?

Tags: halal-haram, non-muslim, wedding

Is it permitted for a Muslim to attend a wedding where a Muslim woman marries a non-Muslim man? Does attending such a marriage indicate support for the wedding?

Comment: rationally, (as you mentioned), whatever shows that you are supporting an act which is against Islam, Hence it won't be permissible (Of course this is my opinion)

Answer (score 3):

Well done, you inquired either a nice or significant matter. As you yourself mentioned in the last part of your question(s), doing this practice (attending a Muslim woman marries a non-Muslim man) would directly or indirectly indicate that you (the Muslim who attends in the mentioned wedding) is supporting and confirming the practice of that Muslim woman. Then Moslems should observe the mentioned issue and do not attend in such wedding.